# Finding the image from a list used in a second image that has an added background

Tags: image, algorithm, computer-vision, comparison

I'm currently working on a project where I have a set of small images with a white background. The user will provide me with an image that contains one of the above images (exactly one, guaranteed), but the image will be on a different background/will have other objects not from the set in it, etc.

Initially I thought this would be an easy application of some machine learning/image comparison algorithm. However, using keypoint matching fails sometimes as a more prominent object gets matched to a different image from the list, or similar.

I don't think this actually requires any ML since the images are identical and I have a very small set (around 500 images), so are there any image comparison algorithms that can handle my case correctly? If not, what kind of pre-processing could I do to increase the accuracy?

Comment: Some sample images might help.

Comment: @MarkSetchell You're right. I'll add some when I get back to my workstation.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the image is exactly the same( no change in pose, orientation, scale etc..)  as you have and only the background is different than i would suggest you use a simple template matching.

So first thing that you will need to do is to extract the little image from the white background. This is an easy step just choose all the pixels in the image that are different than 255 ( or the appropriate background value). This is considered the "Template".

The second stage is to run the "template matching" algorithm for each one of the templates on the test image and look at the value of that as the maximum correlation.

At the final stage choose the template that gave the maximum correlation value as the chosen image.

For a sample code and further explanation you can look at http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html

Comment: scale will be the same, but the actual sizes might be different (ie it might be scaled), further it might be tilted due to the nature of the way it is captured, but the orientation will be correct with respect to the rest of the background (ie, instead of the image appearing as if on a horizontal screen, it'll appear as if the screen were tilted forward or backwards, but always in the correct orientation in that plane that got tilted), would you think it would still work? I haven't read the document yet, but I will soon. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: If you could correct for the orientation before it will still work. If you can't I think you need to look to more advance template matching algorithms or create for each template a bank with different orientations.